# how do I skip symlinks in cmake file GLOB_RECURSE?

Tags: cmake

I would like to find all files match glob pattern but skip the ones are symlinks. What kind of parameters allow me to do this in `file(GLOB_RECURSE)` ?

Comment: Just don't use globs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What kind of parameters allow me to do this in file(GLOB_RECURSE) ?

None, there is no such option. You have to write such code yourself.

> how do I skip symlinks in cmake file GLOB_RECURSE?

Run `file(GLOB_RECURSE` and then iterate over the returned list of paths and remove paths that are symlinks.